# Trouble with nested function, or looking for guidance on a better solution

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, nested-function

I am using bootstrap 4 and would like to change the logo and shrink the navbar on scroll, except when screen size is less than 992px. I believe a nested function may be the best option, but I can't quite get it to work.

Open to other suggestions as well. Thanks in advance...

My code below:

```
function myFunction(x) {
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
      $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','../img/eventlogo_2019-white.svg');
    } else {
      // Collapse Navbar & Change Logo on scroll
  var navbarCollapse = function() {
    if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
      $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");
      $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','../img/eventlogo_2019-white.svg');
    } else {
      $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
      $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','../img/eventlogo_2019.svg');
    }
  };
  // Collapse now if page is not at top
  navbarCollapse();
  // Collapse the navbar when page is scrolled
  $(window).scroll(navbarCollapse);
    }
  }

  var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)")
  myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
  x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should make things easier for you. In this case `MyFunction` will execute at: 1) Document ready event, 2) Window scroll event.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 991px)");
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','../img/eventlogo_2019-white.svg');
    } else {
    // Collapse Navbar & Change Logo on scroll
        if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
            $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");
            $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','../img/eventlogo_2019-white.svg');
        } else {
            $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
            $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','../img/eventlogo_2019.svg');
        }
    }
}

// Call myFunction on document ready event
$(document).ready(myFunction);

// Call myFunction on scroll event
$(window).scroll(myFunction);
```

Comment: Appreciate this Eduardo! This solution seems to be working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need all that complicated JS to achieve what you want. You can just rely on some CSS and very minimal JS (just to store the scroll position). Take a look at this

```js
// store the scroll position on the HTML element so css can react to changes
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  document.documentElement.dataset.scroll = window.scrollY;
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
<!-- use a media query to prevent the change to the header on smaller devices -->
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  <!-- You can check the data-scroll attribute on the HTML node to see if the user has scrolled and set the appropriate styles then, this add a padding to the top of the document -->
  html:not([data-scroll='0']) body {
    padding-top: 3em;
  }
  <!-- this changes the header to fixed and changes the image -->
  html:not([data-scroll='0']) header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url(https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fh260/back_pic/02/65/14/5957873074946eb.jpg);
  }
}
<!-- this is the default style for the header -->
header {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/02/18/34/banner-1018818_960_720.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 3em;
}

h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- initialize the data-scroll attribute on the HTML element -->
<html data-scroll="0">

<head>
  <title>Sample </title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>
      I am your header
    </h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <p>
      I am your content
    </p>
    <p>
      There is a lot of me so i can scroll
    </p>
    <p>
      I am your content
    </p>
    <p>
      There is a lot of me so i can scroll
    </p>
    <p>
      I am your content
    </p>
    <p>
      There is a lot of me so i can scroll
    </p>
    <p>
      I am your content
    </p>
    <p>
      There is a lot of me so i can scroll
    </p>
    <p>
      I am your content
    </p>
    <p>
      There is a lot of me so i can scroll
    </p>
    <p>
      I am your content
    </p>
    <p>
      There is a lot of me so i can scroll
    </p>
    <p>
      I am your content
    </p>
    <p>
      There is a lot of me so i can scroll
    </p>
    <p>
      I am your content
    </p>
    <p>
      There is a lot of me so i can scroll
    </p>
    <p>
      I am your content
    </p>
    <p>
      There is a lot of me so i can scroll
    </p>
    <p>
      I am your content
    </p>
    <p>
      There is a lot of me so i can scroll
    </p>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rfb8m2p6/) is a fiddle so you can easily resize the window to see the effects.

**Edit** - Seems like the snippet viewer messes with the code, just use it to review the code and check it out on jsfiddle for a working example.